# Toshiba Laptop not working printer

Tags: printing

I have a Toshiba Satellite C655D-S5200 with part #PSCOYU--O18001. Originally it had Windows 7 premium black edition, I decided after testing the dual os system with 7 and 13.04. First of all, it won't identify my Cannon Prixma 280 printer and it also won't play my dvds. I have computer desktop that does works, that's a HP Compact Presario 6000 that when I hook up the printer to it the printer it works, The desktop has a dual os system with 7 & Ubuntu thats works just perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once. I wanted to set up a IPP printer

I opened the printer configuration on the computer it worked on and copied the ipp address to the corresponding textbox on the other one.

But at first: Do you have CUPS installed? I have no idea why it shouldn't be, but check it

Then open a browser and go to `http://localhost:631/admin`. Go through the "Add printer" wizard...

As for your DVD's: Do you have `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed?